# Twentyeleven menu wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Im having some troubles with the menú on the wordpress twentyeleven theme.. 
What I want to do is when a user clicks on the menú and goes to the selected page, the "li" stays the same as in hoover.

Here is the page.

http://bit.ly/rUiQsU

I know how to do it in therms of HTML/CSS but I wonder how to do it dynamically. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for the worst english ever.

Comment: I've seen much much worse English here. But just so you know: 1) 'menu' is without the accent, 2) 'hoover' is a vacuum cleaner, or a former head of FBI, 'hover' would be more correct, and 3) 'therms' is a place where you can take a healing bath, 'terms' would be more appropriate here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a dynamic menu, WP puts a class `"current_page_item"` on the current page's li. So, just style that.

Comment: Ah probably. I use `wp_list_pages` which outputs `current_page_item`